# Including Session and Cookie at the firs time in php

Tags: php, session, cookies

Please read patiently.

I have 3 pages form.php ,form_action.php , include.php . Include.php starts a session variable initializing 1 and sets a cookie variable initializing 5 .When the include page is executed I can print the session and the cookie variable respectively 1 and 5 in it.

Next form_action.php includes the include.php page .

The problem arises  when click submit Button of form.php page and it redirects to form_action.php page.
Now if I again write the displaying code of that two variables in form_action.php, it can not display the current values of the session and cookie variable. I t only displays "NULL" .Means form_action.php can not detect that included session and cookies variable firs time.

Again When I refresh the page then it show the exact result , prints the session and the cookie variable respectively 1 and 5 in it form-action.php .What I have to do to see the result at the first time in form_action.php.

Comment: Please enable `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the very beginning of you scripts for debugging to make any error messages show up and post them here.

Comment: But there is not any error!Just can not detect the session and cookie varible at the firs time from the include.php page .I am now trying your solution, ok come back soon and inform you.@Callidior

Comment: Even only if I run this code it shows "Notice: Undefined index: cook in D:\xampp-portable\htdocs\ODESK\include.php on line 6".But when I refresh it it works.                                               <?php error_reporting(E_ALL);                          session_start(); $_SESSION['incluud']=1; setcookie("cook",1,time()+36000); $Cookie=$_COOKIE["cook"]; echo $Cookie; ?> @Callidior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have not started session in `form_action.php`;

Be sure that session started; You can do that in `` `form_action.php `` like

`if(!($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
}`

at the top. If you want to apply `session_start()` to all pages, you can do that in `php.ini`

`session.auto_start=1`

**Edit:** You have misunderstanding about cookies. You cannot get cookie variables right after defined them. In order to get cookie values, they should be sent to browser and you can get them after browser sent. Quick exapmle;

1. When you are making user logged in, you set `setcookie("cook", ....=`. If you try to get $_COOKIE["cook"], you will get noticed, because cookie values was not sent to browser yet
2. User logged in and page redirected to `index.php`, now you can get `$_COOKIE["cook"]` because your cookie value sent to browser and now you can use it

Comment: Even only if I run this code it shows  "Notice: Undefined index: cook in D:\xampp-portable\htdocs\ODESK\include.php on line 6".                              <?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['incluud']=1;
setcookie("cook",1,time()+36000);
$Cookie=$_COOKIE["cook"];
echo $Cookie;
?>  .BUt when I refresh it , it works from second time .@Hüseyin BABAL

Comment: What about `$_SESSION['incluud']`? It is already gives error?

Comment: Notice that now I do not include the include.php page.Just wrote in the browser adress bar "http://localhost:81/odesk/include.php". .But the answer for first time is "Notice: Undefined index: cook in D:\xampp-portable\htdocs\ODESK\include.php on line 6" .@Hüseyin BABAL

Comment: $_SESSION['incluud'] is now working but my main point is to the cookie variable. And $_SESSION['incluud'] name is not problem it may be $_SESSION['Md_Ashikuzzaman'] .But how to work the cookie  $_COOKIE["cook"]; first time now ?@Hüseyin BABAL

Comment: Ok, you have big mistake on cookies :) You cannot get cookie value right after `setcookie`. You need to send it to browser and then you can get. See my updated answer

Comment: Thanks .I have understand .I used the code " if(!isset($_COOKIE["cook"]))
header('Location:include.php');" .At the last of my include.php page . @Hüseyin BABAL

Comment: Yes by using if(!isset($_COOKIE["cook"])) header('Location:include.php');" .Thanks again for your information .

Comment: Hello @ Hüseyin BABAL please notice that this question is voted as -1 . And I am now can't asking any question in stack-overflow now. Please don't forget to vote it up. Thanks.